# Are there any items you can make in which no formula for it exists?

Tags: ni-no-kuni-wrath-of-the-white-witch

In Ni No Kuni, when you get the cauldron, you can make items using the formula you currently have or use the **Mix and Match** option.

Formulae are usually given to you but can you make an item where the formula for it is not given to you? Like making secret items.